# JavaScript variable set from AJAX response is set after it is needed

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

My JavaScript application is having a strange result.

I have some functions that are called which in turn execute an AJAX request, the result of that request is supposed to be set to a variable and then passed on to the next function.

The problem is that the AJAX request is made and then the code keeps moving forward without waiting for the response of the AJAX to set the variables first!

Below is the flow of things...

After DOM has loaded and is ready....

- `projectTaskModal.task.openTaskModalFromUrlHash(hashTaskId);` function is called
- Inside of `openTaskModalFromUrlHash(hashTaskId)` `var taskJsonData = projectTaskModal.task.loadTaskAjaxRequest(taskId);` is ran
- I then print the value of `var taskJsonData` which is `undefined`
- `var taskJsonData` is set from teh result of `loadTaskAjaxRequest(taskId)`
- now inside of `loadTaskAjaxRequest(taskId)` this AJAX call is made...

  ```
      // Request Task Record using AJAX Request to Server
      $.ajax({
          type: 'GET',
          contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
          dataType: 'json',
          url: projectTaskModal.cache.getTaskRecordUrlEndpoint,
          data: {
              action: 'load-task-record',
              task_id: projectTaskModal.cache.taskId
          },
          success: function(data) {

              // Parse JSON data var
              var taskRecordJson = data;
              var task_record = taskRecordJson.task_record;

              // Return Task Record Object
              console.log('task_record var loaded from AJAX SUUCCESS...',task_record);

              projectTaskModal.cache.taskData = task_record;

              console.log('projectTaskModal.cache.taskData', projectTaskModal.cache.taskData);

              return task_record;
          }
      });
  ```
- You can see my AJAX request returns a varible `task_record`
- So `task_record` is supposed to be returned to the `var taskJsonData` in step 3 above, however it is `undefined`!
- Back to my AJAX request, where I print the content of the return to console, it prints the correct data out.

So it seems that for some reason, my code at the top make the AJAX call but then continues on with the execution without waiting for the AJAX response!
So it seems the data is set, it is just set after it is needed!

Now I am using a library called `MockAjax` to intercept my AJAX cals and return Mock data, i've never had this issue though so I am ot sure why it is processing without waiting for my AJAX result to be returned first!

I will make a dmeo if needed, right now my app is about 2,000 lines so I was hoping this is something I could describe first without getting into a demo too much but will if I have to!

THanks for any insight or help

Comment: When you say the code moves forward without setting variables, do you mean the success function fires or you have additional code after the AJAX call that is executing?

Comment: You can't return a value from the success function. AJAX is asynchronous! You need a callback function to do what you want.

Comment: @Daved I just read about setting `async: false ` and that seems to have resolved my issues thanks

Comment: @Hoyen thanks I wasn't aware!  very useful info

Comment: Here is a useful post I found http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-to-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call I'm suprissed I have never had this issue until now, thanks for pointing me in the right direction as I wouldn't of even know it was an issue before!